# Laravel Easier method for key and value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in my database i have many fields into table and i want to need only 3 fields of that. for fetch data from that i have this method:

```
$siteSettings = array();
$siteSettings['site_copyright'] = SystemSetting::find('site_copyright')->value;
$siteSettings['site_generator'] = SystemSetting::find('site_generator')->value;
$siteSettings['site_date']      = SystemSetting::find('site_date')->value;

print_r( $siteSettings );
```

this method is correct and do not have a problem. but whats Easier than this?

Comment: I don't know if it's easier, but it's more efficient if you get all these records, using a single query.

Comment: @Webinan i want to use `eloquent` and my this table of my database is key and value and i want to use simple of `SELECT` with `eloquent` and with object result

Comment: Paste your migrations files or db schema and how the output should look like

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this method?

```
$siteSettings = SystemSetting::get(array('site_copyright', 'site_generator','site_date'));
print_r( $siteSettings );
```

or

```
$fields = array(
    'site_copyright',
    'site_generator',
    'site_date'
);

$siteSettings = SystemSetting::get($fields);
```

Comment: in this method laravel could not get fields from database. `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'site_copyright' in 'field list' (SQL: select 'site_copyright', 'site_generator', 'site_date' from 'setting') `

Comment: Try this: `$test = SystemSetting::where('key', '=', 'site_copyright')->orWhere('key', '=', 'site_generator')->orWhere('key', '=', 'site_date')->get(array('key','value'));`

Comment: this is easier than my used method now?